# toggle with hasClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use hasClass on a toggle and I cant find an example that does what I want. Basically, a button toggles a class back and forth.

Here is the code:

```
$("#sidebar-toggle-btn").click(function() {
  $("#sidebar").toggle();
  if($('#mapDiv').hasClass('col-lg-6')) {
    $('#mapDiv').removeClass('col-lg-6');
    $('#mapDiv').addClass('col-lg-8');
  };
  if($('#mapDiv').hasClass('col-lg-8')) {
    $('#mapDiv').removeClass('col-lg-8');
    $('#mapDiv').addClass('col-lg-6');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/dzo5yg72/

hsz and tushar offered the right suggestions. The reason this wasn't working is because I am an idiot. I was trying to apply the toggle to the wrong button in my interface. So this works:

```
$("#projects-btn").click(function() {
  $('#sidebar').toggle();
  $("#mapDiv").toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-8');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with `.toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-8')`:

```
$("#sidebar-toggle-btn").click(function() {
  $("#sidebar").toggle();
  $("#mapDiv").toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-8');
});
```

Comment: I just tried this and it doesnt work. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Monduiz/dzo5yg72/

Comment: @Monduiz I don't see any element having id `sidebar-toggle-btn` in the fiddle, that is the reason it doesn't seem working. Please create demo with _minimal_ necessary code.

Comment: @Monduiz Here is demo of how toggle class works, http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/usrn8gae/

Comment: Crap, ok I found the problem. First, toggleClass is beautiful and and perfect like Tushar and hsz are saying. It doesnt work because I am an idiot: the ui element it should apply to is projects-btn not sidebar-toggle-btn. It works!

Answer (score 2):

`toggleClass` can accept multiple classes that'll be toggled.

```
$('#mapDiv').toggleClass('col-lg-6 col-lg-8');
```

So, `if hasClass => removeClass else addClass` is same as `toggleClass`.